# the djuint coverage report view didn't update after I run over the junit

Tags: eclipse, junit4

My eclipse is Version: Kepler Service Release 2.

It's OK for the eclipse to generate the coverage report and export them successfully after I run the djunit test.But for some others tests,the coverage report view was't update and when I tried to export them, the eclipse alter java.lang.reflect.InvocatoinTargetException.
And I switch to another computer to run my junit test which can generate the report file successfully.
My doubt is that whether any configuration error on my eclipse ?
 I even try to reinstall my eclipse...

below is the trace
[djunit-coverage-report] djUnit coverage report
[djunit-coverage-report] Exception in thread "main" 
java.io.OptionalDataException
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1370)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2402)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2386)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2418)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at 
java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2418)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(TreeMap.java:2344)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.util.TreeMap.readObject(TreeMap.java:2290)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1180)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at jp.co.dgic.eclipse.jdt.internal.coverage.report.html.HtmlReportGenerator.generate(HtmlReportGenerator.java:99)
[djunit-coverage-report]    at jp.co.dgic.eclipse.jdt.internal.coverage.report.html.HtmlReportGenerator.main(HtmlReportGenerator.java:50)

Comment: Do you use the same Java version on both computers?

Comment: thanks...but both JDK version are 1.7...

Comment: I mean the version on which Eclipse is running (this is usually not a JDK): _Help > About Eclipse_: _Installation Details_: somewhere in the _Configuration_ tab

Comment: Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627.

Comment: I weird that for other junit tests which can generate the coverage report successfully after I ran over the tests...but failed on certain junit test ...(I mean to different java file which has different result)

Comment: I mean the Java version on which Eclipse is running: in the _Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration_ there should be a line that starts with `java.version=`. Is this version the same on both computers?